# Fix code to create a getter/setter property backed by an underlying field

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

From `https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/freeCodeCamp/blob/139eecad25760621d42e482e34b6b57c980b6094/curriculum/challenges/english/02-javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/use-getters-and-setters-to-control-access-to-an-object.md#--instructions--`

> Use the `class` keyword to create a `Thermostat` class. The `constructor` accepts a Fahrenheit temperature.
>
> In the class, create a `getter` to obtain the temperature in Celsius and a `setter` to set the temperature in Celsius.
>
> Remember that `C = 5/9 * (F - 32)` and `F = C * 9.0 / 5 + 32`, where `F` is the value of temperature in Fahrenheit, and `C` is the value of the same temperature in Celsius.
>
> **Note:** When you implement this, you will track the temperature inside the class in one scale, either Fahrenheit or Celsius.
>
> This is the power of a getter and a setter. You are creating an API for another user, who can get the correct result regardless of which one you track.
>
> In other words, you are abstracting implementation details from the user.

```
// Only change code below this line
class Thermostat {
  constructor(temperature) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
  }
  get temperature() {
    return 5/9 * (this.temperature - 32);
  }
  set temperature(updatedTemperature) {
    this.temperature = 9 * updatedTemperature / 5 + 32;
  }
}
// Only change code above this line

const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // Setting in Fahrenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.44 in Celsius
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in Celsius
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, it seems a poor design to use one temperature scale in one place, and another scale right next to it, with no indication that the scales are different.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the value of a variable or subexpression is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a property, otherwise, you are referencing getter and setter while using `this.temperature`)

```js
// Only change code below this line
class Thermostat {
  _temperature = 0
  constructor(temperature) {
    this._temperature = temperature;
  }
  get temperature() {
    return 5/9 * (this._temperature - 32);
  }
  set temperature(updatedTemperature) {
    this._temperature = 9 * updatedTemperature / 5 + 32;
  }
}
// Only change code above this line

const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // Setting in Fahrenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.44 in Celsius
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in Celsius
console.log(temp)
```

You can create a private property by using `#`

```js
// Only change code below this line
class Thermostat {
  #temperature = 0
  constructor(temperature) {
    this.#temperature = temperature;
  }
  get temperature() {
    return 5/9 * (this.#temperature - 32);
  }
  set temperature(updatedTemperature) {
    this.#temperature = 9 * updatedTemperature / 5 + 32;
  }
}
// Only change code above this line

const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // Setting in Fahrenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.44 in Celsius
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in Celsius
console.log(temp)
```